# Typescript: getting type inference for events in an Event Bus

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a very minimal Event Bus, but I am not managing to get Typescript to correctly handle the case in which new event handlers are registered. My code looks like this:

### Here are the types:

```js
interface DefaultEventMap {
  [name: string]: Function;
}

type EventHandlersContainer<T extends DefaultEventMap> = {
  [eventName in keyof T]?: Function[]
}
```

### Here is the actual implementation:

```js
class EventBus<EventMap extends DefaultEventMap> {
  private eventHandlers: EventHandlersContainer<EventMap> = {};

  on<K extends keyof EventMap>(event: K, cb: EventMap[K]) {
    const handlers = this.eventHandlers[event] || [];

    this.eventHandlers[event] = [...handlers, cb]; // <-- TS complains here

    return this;
  }
}
```

### Here is how I would suppose it will be used:

```js
const bus = new EventBus<{
  myEventName: (foo: string) => boolean
}>();

bus.on('myEventName', (str) => str.includes('hello'))
```

Now, everything in this implementation seems to be typed correctly, except that Typescript complains on the marked line: `Type 'EventHandlersContainer<EventMap>[K]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

I've played around, and it seems like TS is thinking that `handler` could be `undefined`. But I don't understand why: if `this.eventHandlers[event]` is indeed `undefined` (which will happen at every first registration of a handler for a particular event), then it should be an empty array, as per the line directly above it.

<kbd>[**Typescript playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIXgVwDZgKIBuE4AsnAA7IDeAUMsgNohwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmAXU4AxTCARhgAexABuGgF8aNMAE9yKQsTAAJOCAAm2aFwDCssHFDQAPABVkEAB6QjXNBjg58RUhQA+ZABeajpGCD8wADlWFFBkAGsINWkYZHtBAH5RcUkZEAZBJRUEbDguD21wACFMLltqsDJKFzdDD3QsXCaWoNp6cj4COEgnKP0jEyguTibJ41MLcGsQO17AkOpFBXDZWwBpJ1diDqSUtOQN8gCACkidTgOAGmQEACM5qJaGA8EASjC9HoCFkPGQAAsDIsZlswBDgFwAHQPcALaZcBiosCCZAAHzxjEEu2ByHhiJRE2hGKxUVxoQYSKZUKmpleH2JyAA9FzkLYALT8jIAZTe0hY5HKoA8EOgEBUpKgEDAmCgIDJCK4CnoymUQA)</kbd>

Comment: If you change `||` to `??`, the error goes away: `const handlers = this.eventHandlers[event] ?? [];`

Comment: Thanks @Terry, would you mind explaining why? According to [MDN Page for nullish coaleshing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) nothing should change compared to `||` if the left-hand side is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but my guess is that TS is not able to understand what is going to be returned from `this.eventHandlers`.

My guess is that K could be either a `number` or `string` (in practice) and he gets lost. I tried to change your code to "help" ts but without success.

As a workaround, you could say to TS: "this is key is a string". I don't see you losing any functionality or breaking anything:

```js
//...
const handlers = this.eventHandlers[event as string] || [];
```

Comment: Mm thanks for the suggestion. Even if in theory `K` could be a number, what would it change? According to the index signature `this.eventHandlers[3]` could only be `Function[]` or `undefined` either way.

As mentioned by one commenter above, the nullish coaleshing seems to work. Could it be a Typescript bug, then?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva Your `DefaultEventMap` says it maps a `string` to a `function`, so in theory it shouldn't allow a number to be used as an index. Maybe TS try to be "smart" on this but he fails. Also I tried to add `on<K extends Extract<key of EventMap, string>>` to force TS to see `K` as a string but it didn't change the behaviour. Maybe it is a bug, I need to investigate a bit more. I also tried to change your types to use `Record<>` but it hasn't worked either

Comment: So... for historical reasons, it seems that TS allows numbers when the index signature is set to `string` allegedly because, when used as indexes, numbers are subsets of strings: see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). However, I still do not see how the problem is related to whether the key is a number or a string.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks! So my hint came when I was hovering the `handlers` variable, when you don't cast `K` as a `string`, I get the type of `handlers` as `EventHandlersContainer<EventMap>[K]`, but when casting `K` to a `string`, then I see the type of `handlers` as `Function[]`, so the error you were having is gone. So I was wondering why TS didn't get the type returned by `this.eventHandlers` when using generics